# How to effectively remove chloramine from tap water

Tags: water, water-treatment

I am looking for a way to remove or substantially reduce chloramine from tap water. From what I learned chloramine is created when ammonia is added to chlorinated water.

It is now a method of choice to disinfect water by many municipalities and from what I read it is much harder to remove than free chlorine itself. I read that activated carbon filter needs more time to remove chloramine than chlorine and that catalytic activated carbon filter can do it faster. Both of these apparently remove only chlorine and still leave ammonia? Is that correct?

How to remove ammonia then? I read that ion exchange can remove it. But then the water will be stripped of all dissolved solids and become acidic? To make it back pH neutral or alkaline I guess there should be another element that adds back minerals.

I basically want to achieve whole house water filtering that will give water free of chloramines and harmful organic compounds and suitable for general use (bath, shower, etc) and ideally also for drinking.

Comment: Small amounts of don't matter, so it's likely safe to bathe and drink. What are you worried about?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26968/test-for-chlorine-and-chloramine-in-city-water-supply

Answer (score 1):

You can use Campden tablets (potassium metabisulfate) to remove chloroamine from water.
The recommended amount is one tablet for 20 gallons of water.